# why does suffixing "\n" add the double quotes in TCL/expect script?

Tags: unix, tcl, expect

the code:

```
exp_send $pass"\n"
```

sends the pass variable value followed by double quotes, newline then double quotes.

I wonder why?

And if I don't want the double quotes to be sent, how should it be coded?

Comment: In Tcl, double quotes only "quote" if they occur at the beginning and end of a word. They are still more special than ordinary text, but in your invocation the quotes will be part of the transferred text. If you just omit the double quotes, you ought to get what you want -- alternatively but unnecessarily you could move the first quote character to before the dollar sign.

Comment: That sounds correct. Thanks!

Comment: Could you link to an example? This is something that occasionally causes confusion, so I might write up an answer that discusses it later.

(I don't know what happened there, I answered a comment that doesn't seem to be here anymore.)

Comment: Sorry. That's me. Edited it as I was checking what I said. I guess what's confusing also is that sometimes send "\n" is written and that sends without quotes but you clarified that already.

Comment: Yes, there is a tendency to overuse double quotes. Sometimes people seem to want to add a visual cue that "this piece of data is a string, and not a keyword or similar". That visual cue confuses rather than clarifies, however. There is also the case of the mini-language that `expr` demands its expressions to be stated in: in that language, *all* strings must be quoted. The syntax rules are very simple, but there is still some confusion around them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to Tcl's [general syntax rules](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). In particular, the `"` character is only special at the start of a word (or after `{*}`, which doesn't apply here). When it is not at the start (and matching end) of a word, it is not special at all.

This means that in:

```
exp_send $pass"\n"
```

The second word consists of the concatenation of the contents of the `pass` variable, a literal `"`, a newline, and another literal `"`. It's *just* the application of the rules.

To fix, you use one of these:

```
exp_send "$pass\n"
```

```
exp_send $pass\n
```

```
exp_send $pass "\n"
```

The third one is different to the other two; it gives two arguments to `exp_send`, not one. The first two options are identical in behaviour, and internally compile to identical bytecode sequences.

Comment: Unfortunately, the third is an error: `exp_send` only takes (-flags and) a single string

Comment: Ah, but that would be a _command-specific_ error and not a general Tcl syntax error. Totally different! ;-)